# convert.exe: invalid argument for option `-crop':

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, crop

convert.exe: invalid argument for option `-crop': '230x53+64+157'-auto-orient @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1154. [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #

I have referred:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

to crop my image.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a space between `157` and `-auto-orient` since it has taken `-auto-orient` as a parameter to `-crop`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply : But i made it work by editing my cropper.rb file

`def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
         " -crop \"#{target.crop_w.to_i}x#{target.crop_h.to_i}+#{target.crop_x.to_i}+#{target.crop_y.to_i}\""
      end
end`

supposedly crop commands will accept only "" ,so I had to use escape characters

previously it was like 
 `" -crop '#{target.crop_w.to_i}x#{target.crop_h.to_i}+#{target.crop_x.to_i}+#{target.crop_y.to_i}'"`